# What is the etymology of lower case p as the operator for the negative of the common logarithm?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, chemistry

In high school we were taught that the formula for pH is the negative of the common logarithm of hydrogen ion concentration: pH = -log[H+].

It wasn't until I took organic chemistry that the "acid dissociation constant" (pKa) was introduced.  It was at that point that the textbook explained that "p" was used as a mathematical operator, meaning the negative of the common logarithm.  (See https://web.mst.edu/~gbert/logs/pH.html.)

Why didn't they teach us that in high school?  There would have been no rote memorization of the pH formula: the equation is right there in the name!

Is this operator restricted to chemistry?  I've never seen it used in a (purely) mathematical context and have always wondered how the usage originated.  Does anyone know its etymology or the first time it appeared in a publication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this...

> **pH**
>   1909, from German PH, introduced by S.P.L. Sörensen, from P, for German Potenz "potency, power" + H, symbol for the hydrogen ion that determines acidity or alkalinity.

[source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ph)

And, yes, it is used only in chemistry.

Answer (score 1):

The term first appeared<sup>[[source]](https://doi.org/10.1021%2Fed800002c)</sup> in S. P. L. Sørensen's paper “Enzyme Studies II” (1909), which did not state what it stood for. Wikipedia [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH#History)<sup>[[permalink]](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=PH&oldid=814222559)</sup> that the meaning of p is disputed between a number of possible words beginning with p (emphasis mine):

> The exact meaning of the "p" in "pH" is disputed, but according to the Carlsberg Foundation, pH stands for "**power** of hydrogen".<sup>[5]</sup> It has also been suggested that the "p" stands for the German ***Potenz*** (meaning "power"), others refer to French ***puissance*** (also meaning "power", based on the fact that the Carlsberg Laboratory was French-speaking). Another suggestion is that the "p" stands for the Latin terms ***pondus*** hydrogenii (quantity of hydrogen), ***potentia*** hydrogenii (capacity of hydrogen), or **potential** hydrogen. It is also suggested that Sørensen used the letters **"p" and "q"** (commonly paired letters in mathematics) simply to label the test solution (p) and the reference solution (q).<sup>[6]</sup>

The source [6] cited ([doi:10.1021/ed800002c](https://doi.org/10.1021%2Fed800002c)) disputes "power" since the article was published in German, French and Danish, but not English. It prefers the *p* and *q* suggestion for the test and reference cells, citing https://doi.org/10.1016/S0968-0004(99)01517-0. This final paper shows that there were equations in Sørensen's papers using the symbols $p_H^+, C_p, C_q, π_p$ and $π_q$.